# How can I import in C#, methods of a class that are passed as a parameter of a function in a unmanaged dll?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke, dllimport

I have an external **API** that gives me a header file (**API.h**) a **dll** and several working examples, but they only work in C++. And I need to use some functions of the **API** (`Connect (), Disconnect (), newuser ()`, etc ...), from an custom website. And I'm looking for alternatives .... to use the minimum code conversion, bridges, etc ...

For now all I see feasible, is to create a WCF web service or a console application. But C++ is a lot of complex for me. So I'm trying from **C#** or **VB**. But while trying to import the **dll** I find the following problem:

I have used the appropriate utility from "*cmd*", and I see that the **dll** file have only 2 functions (exported), that are defined in the **.h** like this:

1-`typedef int (*APIVersion)(void)`; -> I import very easily with [dllimport "my.dll"] and returns an value.

2-`typedef int (*APICreate) (int version, ClassUserInterface **var);` -> This class **ClassUserInterface** (double pointer), is defined in the header file and contains as "public", all the functions I need. E.g. "`virtual int __stdcall Connection (LPCSTR ipserver) = 0;`" also some of these functions uses enums and structures defined in the header.

My goal is to utilize the functions of the `ClassUserInterface` class from C # or VB to continue with my tests.

Does anyone know how I can make these calls related to how consume the class?
The basic import [dllimport "my.dll"] I know how do it.

Best regards

Comment: See [How to Marshal a C++ Class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18032/How-to-Marshal-a-C-Class), but also you could use C++/CLI to build .Net callable wrapper classes.

Comment: This has been asked so many times before. Consuming classes is harder. You are looking for either a COM wrapper or a C++/CLI wrapper or perhaps even a flattening wrapper. No matter what you have some work ahead.

Comment: Thank you very much to both. My problem is I do not know how to approach the project. And I might be trying the most complex way, but I can not find another way to do it. Anyway thanks for the tips. The example of codeproject had seen it, but there's not an example of a class like function parameter .... :(

Comment: Learn C++/CLI. Start by wrapping something simple. Learn the concepts in a throw away test project.